# python program for aggregating a variable in file

Tags: python, fileparsing

I have been trying to read a file in python which has number of viewers for various shows and various channels. I would like to select the shows for the channel 'ABC' and then find the total number of viewers for each of the shows in that channel. The text file is as shown in the following link:

[Text file](https://db.tt/fyY6TUbd)

I have reached a point where I sum the number of viewers for each show without any requirement on if the show is broadcast in the channel 'ABC'. Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
prev_word = ""               
total_views = 0
print_flag = 0

for line in sys.stdin:
    line       = line.strip()       
    key_value  = line.split('\t')   
    curr_word  = key_value[0]       
    value_in   = key_value[1]       
    if (value_in != 'ABC'):
        print_flag = 1
        value_in = int(value_in)
        total_views += value_in
        if (print_flag == 1):
            print (curr_word, total_views)
            print_flag = 0
    prev_word = curr_word
```

Now I'm stuck and I have no idea how to proceed further.

Comment: The file has a format '<string>  <number>'. Which of these is the show/channel/number of viewers?

Comment: The first entry in each line is the show and the second is the number of viewers. There are also lines like: 
Almost_News ABC
So, I would like to print the total numbers of viewers only for those shows which have ABC.